# Create Installer for Java Application Which run as Windows Service

Tags: java, installation, java-service-wrapper

I have requirement to create installer for java application. The application should serve as Native Windows Service.
I have seen following projects which can be used to execute Java Application as Windows Service.

1. [Java Service Wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate-jar-win.html)
2. [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) ....

**Issue:**
As i have to deploy the service on more than 20 systems (Can be increased with passage of time). So i think i would be good enough to create installer and distribute the installer file.

So how i can create installer file for java application which run as Windows Service ?

Comment: Tomcat can run as an windows-service. You can update the tomcat-installer to your needs! You can update tomcat-wars by remote to have your passage of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example, using the [built-in support for Java](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java-service.html) from Advanced Installer.

Advanced Installer will generate at the end an MSI that will install your application, a wrapper EXE that can also run and install as a Win32 service. Along that it contains many other options that could be handy, like an automatic updater, etc...